# Visual Studio Code testing uses different Python version to the terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I'm coding some regression tests for an API in Visual Code. I am using pytest in Python and the testing feature in Visual Studio Code. Most of my tests are fine, however I have one test which creates a virtual network but, it fails because it can't find a certain parameter. If I run the same command manually into WSL extension terminal it runs successfully.

On investigating I noticed Testing is using a different version to Python than if I run it in the Terminal:

From the terminal:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /mnt/c/API Testing
plugins: reraise-2.1.2
collected 1 item
```

From Testing:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.11, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\API Testing
collected 1 item
```

I understand this may not cause the errors I'm seeing but I find it odd there are two different version and I don't see a way to change the version that specifically testing uses.

Has anyone seen this before? or have any suggestions on how I can sync them up?

I have searched the settings and the settings.json file for python versions all seem to be just for the whole Visual Studio Code suite rather than just the testing area

Comment: Not just a different Python version, but a different _operating system_. I'd guess you're using WSL, and VS Code's terminal is aware of that but the testing extension isn't.

Comment: Are you using the "Connect to WSL" option in VSCode or running it straight on windows?

Comment: I`m just using the WSL Extension, is the connect to WSL different?

Comment: I am using WSL and visual code, is there a way I can make testing aware of the different versions I have been through the settings and dont see anything to set that

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial#_python-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python extension will use the interpreter you choose for it, which is the one shown in the lower right corner of the interface. You can modify it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`.

[image]

The terminal will be affected by the system environment variables, and it will use the python environment configured in the environment variable `path`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue, it was @jonrsharpe comment saying they were different OS's.

for some reason it just never really occurred to me I updated python on my laptop and installed pytest it all working as expected now